# Show that $\det(I-xx{^T})=0$ if $x{^T}x=1$

Tags: matrices, determinant

Show that

$$\det(I-xx{^T})=0$$

if $x{^T}x=1$.

Comment: $x^tx = I$ does not quite make sense...

Comment: @TheGeekGreek Sorry, a typo..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard result is $\det (I+AB) = \det (I+BA)$.

Take $A=-x^T, B = x$, then we have $\det (I - x x^T) = 1- x^T x = 0$.

There are various ways to show the identity above, here is one: The non zero eigenvalues of $AB$ and $BA$ are the same, hence we have 
$\det (I+AB) = \prod_{\lambda \in \sigma(AB) \setminus \{0\}} (1+\lambda)  \prod_{\lambda \in \sigma(BA) \setminus \{0\}} (1+\lambda)=  \det(I+BA) $.

Answer (score 6):

If $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of $xx^T$, then $\det(\alpha I-xx^T)=0$. So it suffices to show that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $xx^T$. But this is trivial:
$$
(xx^T)(x)=x(x^Tx)=x.
$$

Comment: Great generalization!